# Dark screen after trying to improve an edit that was already handled

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Here's what happened. I went to a question page and saw that there was an edit pending. I clicked on "edit (1)" to see the edit and somehow got distracted by the cracked.com article link that the editor wanted to add. After I finished reading the article (and some of the comments on said article), I went back and tried to "Improve Edit". After clicking that button the suggested edit popup disappeared and I was left with this:

[image: I know some people wanted a dark theme but this is ridiculous]

As you can see at the bottom of the screenshot (and in the [revision history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/41089/revisions)), someone else had already improved the edit.

Although the darkness can be dismissed with another click, I think it's still worth reporting this.

I'm using Chrome on Mac.